# Pymongo stop index updating while inserting new documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing, pymongo

Is there a way to prevent index updating when inserting new documents (in a `for` loop) ?
I have a multikey index, and the collection is about 2 million documents, so removing the index and recreating it is not practical, since I'm inserting documents in a loop and I do not want an index for the newly inserted ones.

Answer (score 1):

No, updates to indexes are done synchronously as part of the write operation itself.

What is your goal here though, to not index those new documents at all? If so, perhaps creating an appropriate [Partial Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/) would be the correct approach here?

Comment: But what will happen for new insertions with a partial index ? Will the condition be always verified?

Comment: Of course, how else would the database know whether or not to modify the index? But doing (only) that check is still less expensive (both immediately in terms of the write and long term with respect to storage) than adding to the index.  It is absolutely true that you can load data faster without indexes present on the collection, but that's just one consideration overall that should be considered for your particular situation and use-case

Comment: Not updating the index when the document is inserted would be considered a major bug. What are you actually trying to do? improve insert time? Try inserting to a different collection? Merge that collection into the main collection later.